# Is there another idiom to replace "rolling the dice"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, idiom-meaning

Does this sentence sound unnatural?

> The journalist has read the book, written a review and rolled the
>   dice.

I know rolling the dice means to "take a chance". But I am not sure if giving something a score from 1-6 is referred to as rolling the dice, so I wonder if there are other idioms I could have used instead? Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: "Rolling the dice" definitely does not mean "give something a score between 1 and 6". Not at all. In addition, a dice roll is *random* (that's the point) so you've got metaphorical dissonance between that concept and a book critic reading a book, considering it, and deliberately giving it a specific rating. Not to mention that book reviews are usually one out to four, five, or ten, but rarely or never six.... I don't think there's a specific verb or idiom for rating something within a specific range, other than the free-range *rate, review, score, grade* et al.

Comment: Do you want an idiom for assigning a score around 1-6?   Time to bust out the ol' Likert scale...

Answer (score 1):

If the important part is *giving a score or opinion* perhaps ...

> The journalist has read the book, and **nailed his colours to the mast** by publishing his review.

**nail your colours to the mast**  (British & Australian)

> to publicly state your opinions about a subject Nobody knows which way he's going to vote because he has so far refused to nail his colours to the mast.  — [Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/nail+colours+to+the+mast)

Comment: This is a nice, fairly fresh metaphor. OP: Tired metaphors are easy to come by, but fresh ones are valuable, are hard to get, and seldom come but from the pens of good writers. @k1eran has done you a good turn. Now, if the book reviewed regards armored tactics on the Eastern Front during World War II, then nautical images might not work; but otherwise, I recommend k1eran's mast.